# ¡ Porqué el array en un servidor no se actualiza wordpress?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

Aclaro que localmente me funciona como deseo, pero al colocarlo en producción no me funciona por que el arreglo [] esta vacío aun teniendo informacion...

pagina de espera.php

```
    <script>

    (function($){
        
    var variable = '<?php echo $identificador;?>';
    $(document).ajaxStop(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url:'Conexion.php',
            type: 'GET',
                success:function(res){
                    var js = JSON.parse(res);
                    js.forEach(res => {
                        if (res.Id == variable) {
                            location.href='datos_usuario';
                            variable =null;
                        }
                    });
                }
        });
    });

    })(jQuery);

    </script>
```

Conexion.php

```
    <?php
    $db_name = 'name_servidor';
     $db_user = 'user_servidor';
     $db_pass = 'pass_servidor';
     $db_server = 'servidor';


        $conexion = mysqli_connect($db_server, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);

        $select = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM informacion");

        $resp = array();
        while($data=mysqli_fetch_assoc($select)){
            $resp [] = $data;
        }
        echo json_encode($resp);
        
    ?>

    // intente colocar esto mientras tanto pero no me funciono
    $page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    $sec = "3";
    header("Refresh: $sec; url=$page");
```

En la pagina de espera.php no avanza por que el array queda [] aun teniendo informacion. Les agradezco su tiempo y cualquier ayuda.

Intenté colocar el autorefresh con php en la conexion.php para probar pero aun asi no me funciona, no tengo claro de que es lo que pasa ya que localmente me funciona bien. creo que no es necesario mostrar el ajax pero lo dejare por si acaso.

en la pagina de espera es mmientras puppeteer hace un proceso y me inserta a mysql, puppeteer termina e inserta pero recalco que el arreglo en wordpress "Conexion.php" no me actualiza el arreglo para que ajax haga el resto, el problema es que el arreglo queda vacio [] aun teninedo mas de una informacion.

Comment: Hola. ¿Por qué recalcas una y otra vez que *el arreglo está vacío aún teniendo información*? Si tiene información **no puede estar vacío**. ¿Qué depuración has hecho, para afirmar que *contiene información*? El hecho de que funcione en local no significa que deba funcionar en remoto. Por ejemplo, puede que la base de datos en remoto sea otra, o puede que las credenciales de conexión en remoto sean otras.

Comment: Para depurar, agrega **temporalmente** estas tres líneas al inicio de tu script: `ini_set('display_errors', '1');
 ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
 error_reporting(E_ALL);` o activa el modo de DEBUG de Wordpress. Así quizá veas en pantalla más datos sobre el error en remoto.

Comment: Hola, Lo recalco por que se me hace extraño que suceda eso, no se el motivo y efectivamente asi tenga datos me sale vacio, pero si refresco, luego si salen los datos, por eso como prueba coloque el autorefresh con php y aun asi no me funciona si no habro la conexion en otra pestaña.